# Can´t convert string to integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m getting this error while trying to convert string to integer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                              
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                                                           
    n = int(input())                                                                                                                                                            
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'python3 main.py'
```

This is the code:

```
n = int(input())
    if num>0:
        cantPos = cantPos+1
```

Comment: It asks for an integer, and you gave it the name of your file?

Comment: It looks like you typed the command to run your script twice, instead of typing the number that was expected.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not realizing that the interpreter is prompting you for input.  The `input()` function takes a string argument which will be the prompt.  The common pattern to do here is something like:

```
n = None
while n is None:
    try:
        n = int(input('Please enter an integer: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('That was not an integer!')
```